# How do I unclog a sink without a snake or liquid plumber?

Tags: home, sink

So my sink got clogged somehow. I've tried plunging it, but it hasn't seemed very effective. I don't have a snake or liquid plumber on hand though. How can I unclog it?

Comment: What is it clogged with, do you know?  If it's fat or grease, boiling water might do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Take a length of curtain wire:

[image]

Unscrew the "hook" - then thread it GENTLY down the drain and "wiggle it" that should help a lot. Do not force it or push too hard as you will break the pipe if it is plastic.